# Uninstall program by terminal

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, uninstall

How can I uninstall any program using terminal.
 For example, how can I uninstall TeamViewer 7 wich is stored in my home folder. I can not see TeamViewer in ubuntu softvare center, so I can not uninstall it that way.

Comment: If you install TeamViewer 7 using the .deb, you should be able to find it by running `dpkg -l | grep -i teamviewer` then use `dpkg -r` or `apt-get purge package_name` to remove the package with its configuration files.

Comment: Also, if you ever need to remove/purge a package, but you don't remember its exact name but the beginning of it, you can press `Tab` one (or two if there are more options) time(s) to autocomplete what you are typing. For instance, I want to remove Google Chrome: I type `sudo apt-get --purge remove goog` and I press the Tab key two times; the terminal will show me this: `google-chrome-unstable, google-talkplugin, google-musicmanager, goograndom-app` and so on. In this way I can know what packages start with `google`. In case I only have `google-chrome-unstable`, a single Tab will do.

Answer (score 7):

Simple googling might have helped, anyway here is how you can uninstall any package from terminal:

```
apt-get --purge remove <package>
```

You should never remove files by hand use `dpkg --purge <package>` if you have already removed it with apt plus the files by hand and it thinks it is still configured this should get rid of it.

Source of info and more on this you can find here:
[linuxquestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-completely-uninstall-a-package-237772/)